# Does anybody know what happened to Uplodify? It just stopped working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've been using uplodify for a while, but since yesterday it just stopped working.. I have no idea of what happened.... Could you please give a help?

I've already looked for some solutions on the net, however, it was not possible to find anyone. I expect you can help me to solve this problem

You can see my code below:

```
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery/bootstrap/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery/stupidtable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" /> 

    <link href="js/jquery/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="js/jquery/bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="css/admin/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/admin/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/admin/item.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="helpers/uploadfy/css/uploadify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="helpers/uploadfy/js/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="helpers/uploadfy/js/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js"></script>            

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {                
            $('#fupload').uploadify({
                'uploader'  : 'helpers/uploadfy/js/uploadify.swf',
                'script'    : '[baseUri]/admin/uploadr/[item_id]/',
                //'cancelImg' : 'helpers/uploadfy/js/cancel.png',
                'cancelImg' : 'images/icons/cancelb.png',
                'folder'    : 'app/fotos',
                'auto'      : true,
                'multi'     : true,
                'buttonText'  : 'Upload',
                'sizeLimit'   : 25002400,
                'width'       : 275,
                'height'       : 40,  
                //'queueSizeLimit' : 10,
                'uploadLimit' : 1,
                'fileExt'     : '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.bmp;*.jpeg',
                'fileDesc'    : 'Imagens (JPG, GIF, PNG, BMP)',
                //'buttonImg'   : 'helpers/uploadfy/upload.png',
                'buttonImg'   : 'images/icons/uploadr.png',
                'onAllComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj,response){
                    reloadFotoBind();
                },
                'onComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj,response){                        
                    var response = $.parseJSON(response);
                    $(response).each(function(k,v){
                        if(v.id != 'error'){
                            $('<li id="li_'+v.id+'"><img src="[baseUri]/thumb/'+v.url+'/130/100/" id="img_'+v.id+'"/></li>').appendTo('#photo-gallery-ul');
                        }else{
                            $('<li>erro</li>').appendTo('#photo-gallery-ul');
                        }
                    })
                    //window.location = '[baseUri]/admin/item/editar/[item_id]/fotos/';
                }           
            })
        })
    function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) { //v2.0
      window.open(theURL,winName,features);
```

}

Comment: Do you have any errors in the error logs?

Comment: No erros! It was working perfectly until yesterday morning! I have 3 webpages that use the same function, and in all of them it stopped working

Comment: Then there must be errors somewhere.  Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and re-run the scripts.

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me too, so we noticed that the flashplayer was disabled.
We enabled the flashplayer and it worked again.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Tks so much! It worked to me! You've helped me a lot!